# How to change python 3.7 to 3.6 in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I install anaconda in windows and python version is 3.7.  I want to downgrade 3.7 to 3.6 . I used this command in anaconda prompt `conda install python=3.6` . but still when open spyder I can see python 3.7.

Comment: did you try to select Python 3.6 as interpreter under preferences -> python interpreter ?

Answer (score 2):

Open the Anaconda Prompt and try this:

```
conda update conda
conda create -n python36env python=3.6
```

Once the env is created:

```
conda activate python36env
```

To install packages you then run:

```
conda install -c anaconda spyder # or whatever package you want
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try and downgrade anything in your base Anaconda environment. Create a new environment with Python 3.6 and any other packages you want to work with.

If you want to use Spyder with this environment, include the `spyder-kernels` package and activate the environment before starting Spyder.